# Qual a melhor forma de acentuar palavras em arquivos .js?

Tags: javascript, extjs

**Existe uma forma de escrever as palavras da forma que elas são, com seus acentos?**

No php, basta utilizar:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Em javascript, a palavra `Informação` deve ser escrita assim `Informa\u00e7\u00e3o`.

Existe uma alternativa?

Comment: O padrão aceito por todos os navegadores para HTML5 é utf-8. não use iso-8859-1. E escreva a palavra normal, sem tratar os caracteres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure o seu editor de texto (notepad++, sublime, etc) para salvar as edições como UTF-8 ou o charset que achar mais adequado para o seu caso.

Recomenda-se o uso de um conjunto de caracteres multibyte como o UTF-8 (Sem BOM).

**Carregando arquivos .js**

Quando carregar um arquivo JavasScript, recomenda-se também a especificação do charset usado:

```
<script src="file.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**Especifique a meta tag**

No HTML, obviamente, especifique a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Todo o ambiente deve estar bem configurado.

**Caso esteja usando PHP**, especifique o cabeçalho:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

**Observações:**

1. A tag `<meta>` não tem relação com o PHP. É do HTML.
2. Essa resposta aborda o uso do UTF-8, todavia, não quer dizer necessariamente que seja a melhor forma ou a solução definitiva. O uso do UTF-8 é uma recomendação para tornar o charset de sua aplicação internacionalizado pois o UTF-8 suporta caracteres multibyte.

Comment: Obrigado.......